# dependencies и devDependencies работа с зависимостями

Tags: javascript, webpack, npm, node-modules

Не уверен что правильно понимаю как работают зависимости пакетов.

`dependencies` - то что необходимо в продакшене (всякие плагины, библиотеки), `devDependencies` - то что необходимо, для сборки проекта (минификаторы, транспиляторы, компиляторы и тд).

У `bootstrap 5` в объекте `devDependencies` увидел `jquery`. Почему `jquery` не идет в продакшн? Да 5й бутстрап его не использует (в продакшене), но для сборки он ему нужен. Как это работает, например могу ли тот же bootstrap подключить в dev?

UPD:

Как может библиотека пригодиться в разработке и не использоваться в продакшене (на примере JQuery)?

Comment: Всё зависит от цели. Например для разработки удобно использовать SCSS вместо CSS, но это не значит, что на продакшене нужен SCSS. Да и зачем на продакшене заниматься сборкой SCSS, когда можно просто заранее собрать перед релизом и использовать уже готовый CSS. На счёт jQuery, мне кажется его используют в dev, чтобы быстрее разрабатывать, а вот перед релизом, jQuery переводится на нативный JS с поддержкой например IE9 и вполне на этом этапе может быть, что вырезается весь jQuery, и на нативный JS переводится только используемый функционал, что будет весить гораздо меньше чем вся библиотека

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[Перенос комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1408937/dependencies-%d0%b8-devdependencies-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8#comment2505393_1408937)] – Всё зависит от цели. Например для разработки удобно использовать `SCSS` вместо `CSS`, но это не значит, что на продакшене нужен `SCSS`. Да и зачем на продакшене заниматься сборкой `SCSS`, когда можно просто заранее собрать перед релизом и использовать уже готовый `CSS`. На счёт `jQuery`, мне кажется его используют в `dev`, чтобы быстрее разрабатывать, а вот перед релизом, `jQuery` переводится на нативный `JS` с поддержкой например `IE9` и вполне на этом этапе может быть, что вырезается весь `jQuery`, и на нативный `JS` переводится только используемый функционал, что будет весить гораздо меньше чем вся библиотека