# Как правильно распределить npm пакеты в dependencies и devDependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

В процессе разработки понял что в проекте нет разграничения между dependencies и devDependencies.
Помогите грамотно распределить npm-пакеты в dev.
Заранее спасибо!

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "handy-svg": "^1.0.8",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-awesome-reveal": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "use-react-router-breadcrumbs": "^4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Почти такой же вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1408937/dependencies-%d0%b8-devdependencies-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8/1516691#1516691